# Add four spaces at the beginning of every selected new line in batch

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, find-and-replace, styles, text-formatting

In order to add lines of code to a post properly, I'd like to add four spaces (U+0020) at the beginning of every selected new line, the previous line ending in a paragraph break, so that I can just copy and paste from a .docx file.

I suppose it may possibly be done using the Find and Replace option or, failing that, some simple macro instead.

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I've tried working around with wildcards in Find and Replace without any success

Comment: [Find and replace text by using regular expressions (Advanced)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced-eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f#bm8)

Comment: http://www.gmayor.com/replace_using_wildcards.htm . I've also checked this one, but I haven't come up with the right expression yet.

Comment: Try Find what: `(*)^13` Replace with `<space><space><space><space>  \1^p`

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you briefly explain the 'syntax' of such F&R operation please? I'd like to know some basic knowledge about it. Also I do not know how to indicate this is a right answer to solve the post.

Comment: Give me a few minutes and I will write up an answer, which you can accept ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37556/discussion-between-george-jung-and-davidpostill).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I'd like to add four spaces (U+0020) at the beginning of every selected new line

> the previous line ending in a paragraph break

1. Select the paragraphs you want to change.
2. On the "Home" tab, in the "Editing" group, click "Replace" to open the "Find and Replace" dialog box.

> [image]

3. If you don't see the "Use wildcards" check box, click "More", and then select the check box.

> [image]
>
> [image]

If you don't select the check box, Word treats the wildcard characters as text.

4. Set "Find what" to `(*)^13`.

   - `*` matches any string of characters
   - `(*)` groups the string of characters so we can use it in the replace. See below for more explanation.
   - `^13` matches a paragraph break or carriage return
   - `(*)^13` - matches the whole line and groups the text so we can use it in the replace.
5. Set "Replace with" to `<space><space><space><space>\1^p`.

   - `<space><space><space><space>` inserts 4 spaces.
   - `\1` inserts the group `(*)` from the find
   - `^p` inserts a paragraph break.
6. Click "Replace all".

Images sourced from [Find and replace text by using regular expressions (Advanced)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced-eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f) and [Find and Replace using wildcards](http://www.gmayor.com/replace_using_wildcards.htm)

---

#### ()

> Round brackets have no effect on the search pattern, but are used to
>   divide the pattern into logical sequences where you wish to
>   re-assemble those sequences in a different order during the replace –
>   or to replace only part of that sequence. They must be used in pairs
>   and are addressed by number in the replacement e.g.
>
> `(John) (Smith)` replaced by `\2 \1` (note the spaces in the search
>   and replace strings) – will produce `Smith John`
>
> or replaced by `\2` alone will give `Smith`.
>
> Note: The placeholders `\1`, `\2` etc., can also be used in the search
>   string to identify recurring text. e.g.
>
> `Fred Fred` could be written `(Fred) \1`.
>
> Round brackets are perhaps the most useful aspect of complex wildcard
>   search and replace operations.

Source [Finding and replacing characters using wildcards](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/general/usingwildcards.htm)

---

#### Further Reading

- [Find and replace text by using regular expressions (Advanced)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced-eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f)
- [Find and Replace using wildcards](http://www.gmayor.com/replace_using_wildcards.htm)
- [Finding and replacing characters using wildcards](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/general/usingwildcards.htm)